# Display from which repository packages coming from

Tags: debian, repository, kde4

How to add a column, which is displaying package's repository origin in "Software Management/Updates" windows in KDE4?

As far as I remember, at least 6 months ago, I had this feature. It always said stable or testing.

Now it seems I cannot figure out how to get that feature back.

Comment: I can still figure out what repository a package is coming from, by selecting that package -> in its description

Comment: Don't know, but on the CLI, `apt-cache policy <package-name> 
` will do it and there's also `apt-file find <file-name>` to find out what packages have the file you're looking for. The closest thing I found was that the Muon package manager (GUI for apt) has a By Origin button which will let you see all packages from a specific repo and you can sort that by Installed or not and search it too.

Comment: @Joe, thank you, I am going to check this out. But the question regarding integrated Software Manager remains opened

Comment: That's why it was a comment, not an answer.